# How to move drupal 7 site in a different path from Home directory

Tags: 7

what is the way to move drupal 7 site in a different path from Home directory. Currently my website is based on d7, so how i should move drupal 7 site to www.example.com/a/ instead of www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your server setup, it should not be hard. My only recommendation will be to disable the clean urls and the 444 permission of the settings.php file before moving the site over. After the move is done check if the .htaccess file is there, clean the cache, re-enable the clean urls and restore the permissions to the settings.php file to 444.

Comment: something is going wrong over there, by the way, if i delete all the files of d7 and again upload it on a directory and install again under the same database , is this ok? or is there any chance to loss users data, post and related things?

Comment: In theory, no, there should not be a problem on deleting the files and re-uploading them and connect to the existing database. Now, you should be careful if there is any custom made module as it will not be available to download and a similar concept apply to external libraries like JavaScript libraries. If you are having problems moving the files over the new location, changes are that you fighting the file permissions, so change the permissions to a level that will let you move the files then restore the permission level, that way you will not need to re-upload the files.